# In azure container apps, does each revision save its own copy of a docker image?

Tags: azure-container-apps

Since my project is still just in development, when making my builds, I always push and replace a single docker image in ACR with the `:latest` tag. My app is in 'Multiple' revision mode and my build script creates a new revision based on the latest as a template.
Now, I had a persistent  provisioning failure, so I attempted to activate my latest successfully provisioned revision, but it still failed with the same error.

Does each revision need to be created with it's own separate source image, in order for me to be able to return to a previous build if my current one fails? What is the safest approach for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does each revision need to be created with it's own separate source image, in order for me to be able to return to a previous build if my current one fails? What is the safest approach for production?

Yes, the image isn't copied. It'll be pulled from your registry every time the revision is activated or scales out or moves between VMs.

You can use a git commit id or a build version for the image tag.